# Optional/dynamic form fields in AngilarJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

Let's imagine a following form:

```
First Name: string
Last Name: string
Married: checkbox
% the following should be shown once checkbox is ticked %
Partner First Name:
Partner Last Name:
[Submit]
```

What is the most ellegant way of doing a form with optional fields in AngularJS?

Comment: do you mean using angular external module

Comment: User ng-show directive for Partner First Name and Partner Last Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming check box `ng-model="married"` add ng-show attribute to those optional fields set with the value "married" `ng-show="married"`